# Passing Message in Google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am learning about chrome extensions and having a hard time understanding passing of messages.

To understand this better I have a button and on click it will turn content on page red, and if there is content to update the title of the pop up itself.

But I keep getting errors:

"Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."

(inside of chrome extension dev tool)

and

"Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://jhpandehcddbmdcjiaioihimniapmpci/content_script.js:8:29"

(on active page dev tools)

Could anyone point to good resources or a simple solution for this?

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "My ExTeNsIoN",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "My Extension",
"permissions": [
    "tabs","<all_urls>"
    ],
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery-3-4-0-min.js", "content_script.js"]
    }]

}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Extension</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="the_title"></h1>

<input type="submit" id="color_button" value="Change Color">

<script src="jquery-3-4-0-min.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
   $("#color_button").on("click",function() {
 chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log("sending hello greeting.");
  });
  });
 })



chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.greeting == "hello_2") {
    $("#the_title").text("This Worked!");      
  }
 });
```

content_script.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

  if (request.greeting == "hello") {
    $("p").css("color","#ff0000");

        if($("p")) {

            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello_2"}, function(response) {
                    console.log("sending hello_2 greeting.");
            });
          });
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: A content script runs alongside a web page and can use just a few `chrome` API. It can't use chrome.tabs. What exactly are you trying to do? Theoretically you could use chrome.runtime.sendMessage, but there's a better approach - simply send a response as indicated in the messaging documentation.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm , 

Basically I am trying to create a extension to scrape a site, I wanted to have this click a button on the popup.html, then scrape the page for the data I need on content script, then send that data back to the popup, just struggling to understand how to pass this data back to the pop up

Comment: Remove chrome.tabs.query and replace chrome.tabs.sendMessage with chrome.runtime.sendMessage in your content script. Or maybe you don't even need to declare a dedicated content script, just use chrome.tabs.executeScript with literal code in the popup script to get the results back ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39806930)).